# Who were the famous scientists in the post-war British nuclear weapon project?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-weapons

The Manhattan project is well known for gathering many top scientists of the century. The Soviet nuclear program seem to have a reduced but still important cast with scientists like Andrei Sakharov, Vitaly Ginzburg and Yakov Zeldovich.  The German *Uranverein* had Werner Heisenberg, Walther Gerlach and Otto Hahn.

However when it comes to other nuclear programs it is not very clear who contributed. This question is about the postwar British nuclear bomb but I may ask similar questions about the French.

I am surprised that people like James Chadwick, Rudolf Peierls or Otto Frisch, who contributed a lot in UK affairs and the Manhattan project do not seem to have been involved in the postwar British program (or at least I could not find any information about their contribution).

I could find only that Baron Penney (from Kronig-Penney model) was the leading scientist. But who were the other importants scientists in the UK post-war nuclear bomb project? Any famous scientists were also involved?

So far I have only found the names of John Challens and John Corner. Others like Roy Pilgrim, Ernest Mott and Cecil Bean are mostly unknown outside the project and do not have a Wikipedia page. Special mention to Klaus Fuchs that also worked on Manhattan and in the British program, and was later arrested for being a Soviet spy.

Comment: Frisch was involved initially. Cockcroft was the first head of AWE. Skinner was a fellow of the Royal Society. And others. Depends on how ‘famous’ you think they are.

Comment: @JonCuster are you sure Frisch was involved in post war efforts? Do you mean AERE (not the same) for Cockcroft? I have the same problem with Skinner, not sure how well known he is.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Explosive_Research Was the original project, leading to AERE and AWRE (later AWE). It’s complicated…

Comment: I would be interested in anything you discover about Roy Pilgrim. He was my grandad but was always very provate about his work so we really know very little about it.