# Who were some of the scientists in the post-war French nuclear weapon project?

Tags: france, atomic-weapons

The Manhattan project is well known for gathering many top scientists of the century. The Soviet nuclear program seem to have a reduced but still important cast with scientists like Andrei Sakharov, Vitaly Ginzburg and Yakov Zeldovich. The German Uranverein had Werner Heisenberg, Walther Gerlach and Otto Hahn.

However when it comes to other nuclear programs it is not very clear who contributed. This question is about the postwar French nuclear bomb. I asked a similar question about the British: [Who were the famous scientists in the post-war British nuclear weapon project?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15595/who-were-the-famous-scientists-in-the-post-war-british-nuclear-weapon-project)

I am surprised that people like Pierre Auger or Jules Guéron, who contributed a lot in the Manhattan project (from Canada) do not seem to have been involved in the postwar French program (or at least I could not find any information about their contribution).

As far as I know, Fréderic Joliot-Curie was against the bomb even if he created the  *Commissariat à l'énergie atomique* (CEA).

I could find only that Bertrand Goldschmidt was the leading scientist but I am unable to find any other scientists just politicians and military men. Even in the French articles of Wikipedia *[Histoire du programme nucléaire civile de la France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_du_programme_nucl%C3%A9aire_civil_de_la_France)* and *[Histoire du programme nucléaire militaire de la France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_du_programme_nucl%C3%A9aire_militaire_de_la_France)* there is just a mention of Goldschmidt and no other scientist. But who were the other scientists in the French post-war nuclear bomb project? Any famous scientists were also involved? Is this still confidential?

Comment: As an aside, consider the state of the US weapons program in, say, 1950 - what ‘famous’ scientists were active in it still?

Comment: @JonCuster for the hydrogen bomb you still had Lawrence, Bethe, Teller and Ulam.

Comment: Bethe was back at Cornell. Lawrence was focused more on Lawrence Berkeley Laboratory and big science facilities. Teller and Ulam did remain (well, Ulam left and came back to Los Alamos).

Comment: @JonCuster by the few I could just see in Wikipedia (please correct me again if I am wrong), Lawrence [seems to have actively participated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest_Lawrence#Thermonuclear_weapons) nevertheless. Do you have anything I could check on Bethe? he seems to have been a key player to the point people miscalled him the father of the H-bomb.

Comment: Bethe was involved with development of the H-bomb, but did so while also being a professor at Cornell. Many 'original' Manhattan Project folks returned to their previous employment after the war, some consulting as well with Los Alamos. Bethe returned to consult because he felt the world situation made it necessary to determine if an H-bomb might work (similar to the original worries around the A-bomb and the Germans). But once WW2 was over, weapon development (US, USSR, UK, France) became more an engineering effort, not a bleeding edge science effort.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks for the details. Yeah, I am under the impression that the research was pretty almost over after the Manhattan project. I have modified the the question to lower the requirements in accordance to the little amount of info I have found so far.

Comment: The [French & Israeli nuclear scientists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction) co-operated in the development of French nuclear weapons. The also secretly built a nuclear reactor and plutonium processing plant at Dimona, for Israel in the 1950s.  When France tested its first nuclear bomb in 1960, French President De Gaulle decided to distance France's nuclear weapons program from Israel's.

Comment: @Fred do you have names of the scientists?

Comment: When it comes to nuclear weapons & their Dimona plant, Israel is very secretive. Check out the [Vela Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vela_incident).

Comment: Bethe's supreme [memo](https://nuke.fas.org/guide/usa/nuclear/bethe-54.htm).

Comment: [H. Bethe, 1982](https://library.lanl.gov/cgi-bin/getfile?00285791.pdf). Required reading.

Comment: @CosmasZachos what has any of this to do with the French program?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, except Bethe's name was taken in vain in the conversation above... Bethe was actually opposing the original bad idea of the H-bomb, which might be termed "involvement"....

Comment: The article you linked is the history of the French *civil* nuclear program. There is another article for the *military* nuclear program (although a lot of the content is copy/pasted): https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histoire_du_programme_nucl%C3%A9aire_militaire_de_la_France But no fancy names in here, it was mostly done by anonymous engineers. You don't necessary need famous people to do science...

Comment: Because designing power plants and bombs are two very different things?

Answer (score 1):

Providing a partial response here to my own question. However I have still to find a proper document with a list or names. Here is a recap of what I got:

- As I said, Fréderic Joliot Curie was not in there, he was against the
  nuclear weapon project and was kicked out of the CEA.
- [Bertrand Goldschmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_Goldschmidt) is considered the father of the French
  atomic bomb and was leading the project until 1960. He had very little public appearance.
- [Yves Rocard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yves_Rocard), father of some famous French minister, responsible for the French atomic program and took over Joliot-Curie, and also called father of the French bomb. He is kind of interesting because he became obsessed with UFOs and alternative medecine when he got older.
- [Francis Perrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Perrin_(physicist)), son of famous French experimental physicist [Jean Perrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baptiste_Perrin) and brother-in-law of [Pierre Auger](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Auger) (who participated in the Canadian-wing of the Manhattan Project). He was the one that revealed that there was some kind of cooperation on nuclear research between France and Israel. He also discovered the only natural nuclear reactor in the Oklo mine, Gabon.

- [Robert Dautray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Dautray), engineer scientist and another CEA director. He said to be the Father of the French atomic bomb (how many are there?). However this claim has been contested.
- Engineer [Michel Carayol](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Carayol) worked on the design of the H-bomb.

I am still looking for a deeper source.

Comment: About Frédéric Joliot (1935 Nobel Prize of Chemistry with his wife Irène Curie) : he has been excluded because of his deep involvement into the French Communist Party (not only a "compagnon de route" like many intellectuals in post-war France). For those who read french, see the very interesting site https://www.cinearchives.org/Trombinoscope-Frederic-Joliot-Curie-443-819-74-0.html